# Javascript : function statement requires a name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with a row that looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="265"></td>   
                 <td>265</td>
                    <td>NO MATCH</td>
                    <td>NO MATCH</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>f79a8316891</td>
              </tr>
```

I am trying to build a jquery function that will highlight a cell only if it starts with "NO" . So far I have:

```
$( "td" ).hover( function() {
    var contents = $( this ).html() ;
    if (contents.match("^NO")) {
            function() {
            $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
            }, function() {
            $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
            }
    }   


  });
```

But I'm getting the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax for your `hover()` function is way off. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is this `function() {` supposed to do there?

Comment: You define a function with no name and no immediate invocation. There is no way for that function to be called (that's why you get the error). Also, don't define a function in an `if` statement. This is bad because JavaScript doesn't have block scope for defining functions.

Comment: I started from the example at http://api.jquery.com/hover/ to try to build this. i then tried to put an if statement around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the functions in the wrong place. Try something like this:

```
$( "td" ).hover( function() {
    var contents = $( this ).html() ;
    if (contents.match("^NO")) {
        $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );

    }   
}, function() {
        $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
});
```

The jQuery hover function takes two functions as it's parameters, the first for 'mouse over' and the second for 'mouse out'. You simply put these functions in the wrong place in your original code. For more information on hover, see http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Its worth being clear (for the sake of the OP and future visitors) that the problem was that the jquery `hover` method takes 2 functions as arguments - one to execute when the mouse goes over and the second when the mouse moves out of the element.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, I wasn't very detailed on the explanation, I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks Jamiec, I started from the example at api.jquery.com/hover to try to build this. I then tried to put an if statement around it. I didn't understand that there were 2 arguments for hover.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to add and remove stuff on hover. Simply find all the cells that match your criteria (using [jQuery's filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)) then give them a class. You can then style `.nomatch` elements as you see fit. Here I've added the triple-star text on hover as per your requirements.

```js
$(function(){
  var key = "NO";
  var $cellsBeginWithNo = $("td").filter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text().indexOf(key) === 0){ //if text begins with [key]
        $this.addClass("nomatch");       //give it a class
        return $this;                    //add it to our collection
    }
    return false;
  });
  /* 
    Now you have a jQuery collection of matched elements that you can apply further functions to if you like. EG: 
    $cellsBeginWithNo.on("click", function(){alert("click");});
  */
});
```

```css
td.nomatch {
    background-color:#ffeeee;
}
td.nomatch:hover:after {
    content : " ***";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="265"></td>   
        <td>265</td>
        <td>NO MATCH</td>
        <td>NO MATCH</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>f79a8316891</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```